# Can I export an animation as an .anim file format?

Tags: animation, export

Another board suggested exporting animations made in Blender (in this case it is a character animation that will be played in Second Life or a similar platform) as an .anim file.

I have done lots of searching on Google and looking in the program. It seems like .anim is a MAYA extension?  Is it actually possible to export your animation as an .anim file?

If so, some hints would be helpful.

Comment: Never heard of that file format, I don't think Blender can export .anim directly, not sure. If it's a Maya format maybe you can export an FBX from Blender into Maya, and from there export the .anim file. Otherwise if it's for Second Life see if this helps http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Mesh/Exporting_a_mesh_from_Blender also here https://community.secondlife.com/t5/Animation-Forum/Blender-Animations/td-p/1291429